# display a screen/frame to display dicom image in matlab

Tags: matlab, dicom

I have a matlab program to upload  a folder of dicom images. I want to display a black screen/frame where in the image would be loaded. Now, the image is displayed over the browse button.

Is there a way to do it ?

Here's my code:

```
function varargout = ui(varargin)
% UI MATLAB code for ui.fig
%      UI, by itself, creates a new UI or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = UI returns the handle to a new UI or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      UI('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in UI.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      UI('Property','Value',...) creates a new UI or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before ui_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to ui_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help ui

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 17-Nov-2015 13:11:51

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @ui_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @ui_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
end
% --- Executes just before ui is made visible.
function ui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to ui (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for ui
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes ui wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);
end

% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = ui_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure

varargout{1} = handles.output;
end

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global files;
global dname;
dname = uigetdir('Select the dicom image folder');
set(handles.text2, 'String', dname);
files = dir(fullfile(dname, '*.dcm'));
dname = [dname '\'];
global indexSelected;
indexSelected = 1;
filePath = [dname files(1).name];
fileRead = dicomread(filePath);
imshow(fileRead, []);
end

function text2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to text2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of text2 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of text2 as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
end

function text2_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to text2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
end

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global indexSelected;

global files;
global dname;
if(indexSelected == 1)
    indexSelected = length(files);
    filePath = [dname files(indexSelected).name];
    fileRead = dicomread(filePath);
    imshow(fileRead, []);
else
    indexSelected = indexSelected - 1; 
    filePath = [dname files(indexSelected).name];
    fileRead = dicomread(filePath);
    imshow(fileRead, []);
end
end

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global indexSelected;

global files;
global dname;
if(indexSelected == length(files))
    indexSelected = 1 ;
    filePath = [dname files(1).name];
    fileRead = dicomread(filePath);
    imshow(fileRead,[]);
else
    indexSelected = indexSelected + 1;
    filePath = [dname files(indexSelected).name];
    fileRead = dicomread(filePath);
    imshow(fileRead,[]);
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In short:

- You can fix your problem by adding an `axes` in your GUI in the position (and with the size) in which you want to display the image
- You should add in your `callback` some checks in order to catch the following situations:

  - the users selects `Cancel` when selecting the folder
  - the selected folder does not contains any `.dcm` files
- `pushbutton2` and `pushbutton3` should be `disabled` when the GUI is opened and then enabled in the `pushbutton1` callback if the users selected a right folder. You can disable them either using `GUIDE` or setting their `enable` property `off` in the GUI `CreateFcn`
- Also you can avoid using `global varaibles`; you can actually store and share variables among the `callback` by using the `guidata` built-in function.

**Adding the axes**

After having added the `axes` (with, for example, `tag` axes1) you can set its appearence in the `CreateFcn`:

- you can set a black background color using `set` function
- you can remove X-axis and Y-axis `ticks` using `set` function as well

You can insert this `callback` in your code

```
% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function axes1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to axes1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: place code in OpeningFcn to populate axes1

% Set axes background color to black
set(hObject,'color','k')
% Remove X-axis and Y-axis ticks
set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
% Disable pushbutton2 and pusbutton 3 (they will be enabled in pushbutton1
% callback)
set(handles.pushbutton2,'enable','off')
set(handles.pushbutton3,'enable','off')
```

When the `imshow` function is called in your `pushbutto callback` the `DICOM` image will be displayed in the right position.

**Adding checks on folder selection**

You can simply test the value returned by `uigetdir`: it is set to `0` when the user pushes `Cancel` or

**Using GUI data instead of flobal variables**

You can store the varaibles you want to share among the `callback` adding them to the GUI data struct.

In the GUI `OpeningFcn` you can initialize (if needed) the varaibles you want to share by adding the following code:

```
% Add "indexSelected" to handles struct and initialize it
my_gui_data=guidata(gcf)
my_gui_data.indexSelected=0;
guidata(gcf,my_gui_data);
```

The function `guidata` is used at the beginning to get the GUI data from the GUI (at the beginning it only contains the GUI handles).

Then you can add the `indexSelected` to the GUI data struct and set the updated GUI data struct by calling again `guidata`.

When you need to retrieve and / or update the variables in the `callback` you just have to use the same approach. For example, to store the `dname` varaible in the `pushbutton1_Callback`

```
my_gui_data=guidata(gcf)
my_gui_data.dname=dname;
guidata(gcf,my_gui_data);
```

I've created a GUI (dcom_gui) to test the above suggestions:

```
function varargout = ui(varargin)
% UI MATLAB code for ui.fig
%      UI, by itself, creates a new UI or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = UI returns the handle to a new UI or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      UI('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in UI.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      UI('Property','Value',...) creates a new UI or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before ui_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to ui_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help ui

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 21-Nov-2015 17:35:56

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @ui_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @ui_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before ui is made visible.
function ui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to ui (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for ui
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% Add "indexSelected" to handles struct and initialize it
my_gui_data=guidata(gcf)
my_gui_data.indexSelected=0;
guidata(gcf,my_gui_data);

% Disable pushbutton2 and pusbutton 3 (they will be enabled in pushbutton1
% callback)
set(handles.pushbutton2,'enable','off')
set(handles.pushbutton3,'enable','off')



% UIWAIT makes ui wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = ui_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get GUI data
my_gui_data=guidata(gcf)

% Use guidata data struct instead of "global" variables
% global files;
% global dname;
dname = uigetdir('Select the dicom image folder');

% Check for directory selection validity
if(dname == 0)
   set(handles.text2,'string','Dir selection aborted')
else
   set(handles.text2, 'String', dname);
   files = dir(fullfile(dname, '*.dcm'));
   % Check for files presence
   if(length(files) == 0)
      set(handles.text2,'string',['No ".dcm" file in ' dname ' folder'])
   else
      % Enable pushbutton2 and pusbutton 3
      set(handles.pushbutton2,'enable','on')
      set(handles.pushbutton3,'enable','on')

      % Use guidata data struct instead of "global" variables
      % global indexSelected;

      % Not needed, use fullfile to build the full file name
%       dname = [dname '\'];
      indexSelected = 1;
%       filePath = [dname files(1).name];
      filePath = fullfile(dname,files(1).name);
      fileRead = dicomread(filePath);
      imshow(fileRead, []);
      % Store GUI data
      my_gui_data.dname=dname;
      my_gui_data.files=files;
      my_gui_data.indexSelected=indexSelected;
      my_gui_data.filePath=filePath;
      guidata(gcf,my_gui_data);
   end
end

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Use guidata data struct instead of "global" variables
% global indexSelected;
% 
% global files;
% global dname;
my_gui_data=guidata(gcf);
indexSelected=my_gui_data.indexSelected;
files=my_gui_data.files;
dname=my_gui_data.dname;

if(indexSelected == 1)
   indexSelected = length(files);
   % Use "fullfile" to build the file name
%    filePath = [dname files(indexSelected).name];
   filePath = fullfile(dname,files(indexSelected).name);
   fileRead = dicomread(filePath);
   imshow(fileRead, []);
else
   indexSelected = indexSelected - 1;
   % Use "fullfile" to build the file name
%    filePath = [dname files(indexSelected).name];
   filePath = fullfile(dname,files(indexSelected).name);
   fileRead = dicomread(filePath);
   imshow(fileRead, []);
end
% Store GUI data
my_gui_data.filePath=filePath;
my_gui_data.indexSelected=indexSelected;
guidata(gcf,my_gui_data);


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Use guidata data struct instead of "global" variables
% global indexSelected;
% 
% global files;
% global dname;
my_gui_data=guidata(gcf);
indexSelected=my_gui_data.indexSelected;
files=my_gui_data.files;
dname=my_gui_data.dname;

if(indexSelected == length(files))
   indexSelected = 1 ;
   %  Use "fullfile" to build the file name
   % filePath = [dname files(1).name];
   filePath = fullfile(dname,files(1).name);
   fileRead = dicomread(filePath);
   imshow(fileRead,[]);
else
   indexSelected = indexSelected + 1;
   %  Use "fullfile" to build the file name
   % filePath = [dname files(indexSelected).name];
   filePath = fullfile(dname,files(indexSelected).name);
   fileRead = dicomread(filePath);
   imshow(fileRead,[]);
end
% Store GUI data
my_gui_data.filePath=filePath;
my_gui_data.indexSelected=indexSelected;
guidata(gcf,my_gui_data);


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function axes1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to axes1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: place code in OpeningFcn to populate axes1

% Set axes background color to black
set(hObject,'color','k')
% Remove X-axis and Y-axis ticks
set(gca,'xtick',[],'ytick',[])
```

**The GUI just opened**

[image]

**The GUI with a DCOM image**

[image]

Hope this helps.